# EventListener function throwing error

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Web development and trying to create a simple project.
I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="ansBox"><p class="ansBoxP"></p></div>
    <div class="ansBox"><p class="ansBoxP"></p></div>
    <div class="ansBox"><p class="ansBoxP"></p></div>
    <div class="ansBox"><p class="ansBoxP"></p></div>
    <div class="ansBox"><p class="ansBoxP"></p></div>
    <div class="ansBox"><p class="ansBoxP"></p></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to compare the value in the paragraph to the answer set and display a message.

```
var ansBoxP = document.querySelectorAll(".ansBoxP");
var ansBox = document.querySelectorAll(".ansBox");

function setSquares() {

for(var i=0; i<numSquares; i++) {
    ansBox[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        // Get value of square picked
        var clickVal = ansBoxP[i].textContent;
        console.log("click is " + clickVal);

        if(clickVal == answers[i]) {
            alert("corrent");
        }
        else {
            alert("incorrect"); 
        }
    });
  }
}
```

However i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>
```

I believe the issue is with how I am setting the clickVal variable. Am I correct in saying this is a scoping issue?

Comment: `console.log(i)` inside the event handler, see what you get.

Comment: `document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener("click", function(e){
     if (e.target.tagName=="P") {   var clickVal = e.target.textContent; ...`